# UITableView Pull to Refresh not showing the label and the spinner

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitableview

I'm trying to implement the Pull to refresh to my UITableView. The effect from pull works and the refresh works fine! But the labels

> loading, pull to refresh and the spinner not appear in my tableView.

here is my code which add the view refresh to the tableview

if I change the

> refreshHeaderView's frame

to

```
   refreshHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,  REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT, 300, REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT)];
```

the labels and spinner appear! But above the first cell!

```
- (void)addPullToRefreshHeader {
refreshHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0 - REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT, 300, REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT)];
refreshHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

refreshLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT)];
refreshLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
refreshLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
refreshLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

refreshArrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
refreshArrow.frame = CGRectMake(floorf((REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 27) / 2),
                                (floorf(REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 44) / 2),
                                27, 44);

refreshSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray
                  ];
refreshSpinner.frame = CGRectMake(floorf(floorf(REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 20) / 2),    
       floorf((REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 20) / 2), 20, 20);
refreshSpinner.hidesWhenStopped = NO;

[refreshHeaderView addSubview:refreshLabel];
[refreshHeaderView addSubview:refreshArrow];
[refreshHeaderView addSubview:refreshSpinner];
[self.tbFeeds addSubview:refreshHeaderView];
  }
```

> EDIT

I did solve my problem with the following changes:

> ```
> - (void)addPullToRefreshHeader {
> refreshHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 108, 300, REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT)];
> refreshHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
>
> refreshLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT)];
> refreshLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
> refreshLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
> refreshLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
>
> refreshArrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
> refreshArrow.frame = CGRectMake(floorf((REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 27) / 2),
>                                 (floorf(REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 44) / 2),
>                                 27, 44);
>
> refreshSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray
>                   ];
> refreshSpinner.frame = CGRectMake(floorf(floorf(REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 20) / 2),
> floorf((REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 20) / 2), 20, 20);
> refreshSpinner.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
> [refreshHeaderView addSubview:refreshLabel];
> [refreshHeaderView addSubview:refreshArrow];
> [refreshHeaderView addSubview:refreshSpinner];
> [viewGeral addSubview:refreshHeaderView];
> [viewGeral bringSubviewToFront:_tbFeeds]; }
> ```

Comment: Why don't you use one of the many options on github as the basis for your work, then add the bits that are missing (arrow image?)?

Comment: I'm following a project from github..but when I implement in my project...

Comment: why not use UIRefreshControl? iOS 6.0+